# Undefined Variable trying to show GeoLocation on Magento 2 product page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, blocks

I am trying to look up the visitor's location and show this on the product page. It's going to be used to send them a personalised message based on location but currently, I am struggling to get it to show the current state.

If I put the code in a normal PHP file and load this it works fine but when I try this on a custom block in a .phthm file I get an error loading the product page saying undefined variable.

I can pull product details but not sure how I correctly define and show this on a product page.

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: ip in
>   /home/staging/public_html/app/code/drumbeat/tabmodule/view/frontend/templates/shipping2.phtml
>   on line 76

```
<?php 

function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    $state=NULL;
    $ip=NULL;
    global $ip;
    global $state;

    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    // return $output;
}

?>
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p><?php echo $ip('State'); ?></p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this method I used jQuery Instead as below,

In case helps anyone:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
    $("#ip").append("Your IP is: " + response.ip);
    var regionChk = response.region;
    switch (regionChk)
        {
           case "England":
            $("#region").append("100% FREE 1-Day Delivery " + response.region);
            break;


                case "Wyoming":
            $("#region").append("100% FREE 2-Day Delivery ");
            break;

           default:
               $("#region").append('100% FREE 3-Day US Shipping' + response.region);
        }
    }, "jsonp");
});
</script>
```